# How can I create a template ascending sort function that takes in any type of data (int, char *, custom)?

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, c++17

Like the title describes I am trying to create a function that can sort any data type vector in ascending order. Right now all I'm working with is a standard sort function:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to modify this code to be able to work for things like char *.

I've created overload operators for ">" and "<" in my custom function, but I realize I can't invoke them in a way that also compares integers by default. I'm really lost on what to even try next, and can't seem to wrap my head around it. I think I'll need a different function that they sort function would call for at least my custom data type, but I have no idea what I would put in it and what the main sort function would then look like.

Another idea I had is to create 3 smaller functions for the integers, char *, and custom data type, and each would be called respectively in the main sort function, but then I wouldn't know how to make the main a template function, or if its even a template function at all at that point.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Just do what you're already doing. This should invoke the overloaded `operator>`. But consider to only rely on `operator<`, that's at least what the standard library does.

Comment: You cannot overload operators for basic built-in types. And you don't have to. And anyway, you must not _"overload operators [...] **in** my custom function"_ : A function's body is not a place where to define overloads or anything.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a confusion about what a "template function" is. Could you please show the *whole* function (including its signature) you wrote? Are you aware of [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)? Do you know how to pass a function object to a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use `std::sort`. Failing that, *copy the signature* of `std::sort`, including any template parameters, and work from it.

Comment: "I'm working with is a standard sort function" - no, what you are working on is known as "bubble sort", and it is terribly inefficient. There is *the* standard sort function `std::sort`.